# Не добавляются сторонние стили в дочерней теме для шаблона Storefront

Tags: wordpress

Сделал дочернюю тему для Storefront по [инструкции](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html).

В файле /wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/[class-storefront.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/blob/master/inc/class-storefront.php) подключаются стили и скрипты. (строка 204)

Мне нужно добавить свои стили, например bootstrap, копирую файл class-storefront.php в свою тему /wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/class-storefront.php и оставляю там только функцию

```
public function scripts() {
  global $storefront_version;

  /**
  * Styles
  */
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', array("storefront-style") );
}
```

bootstrap в head не подключается, положил его и в /wp-content/themes/storefront/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css и в /wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css все равно не подключился.

Что у меня не так с class-storefront.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Что происходит**

Далеко не все файлы темы можно копировать в дочернюю и ожидать, что они будут подхвачены. Обычно это специально указывается разработчиками в комментариях, в самом верху php-файла.

Откройте, например файл `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php` из плагина WooCommerce и прочитайте комментарий вверху. Этот функционал обеспечивается кодом плагина.

Некоторые основные файлы темы вроде `header.php`, `footer.php`, `page.php` и т.д., подхватываются ядром WordPress, если они присутствуют в дочерней теме.

**Что делать**

Файл `class-storefront.php` содержит определение класса. Вы можете создать свой класс-наследник от `class Storefront` и подменять в нем функции.

Но для вашей задачи вам и это не нужно. Вставьте такой код в functions.php дочерней темы:

```
function my_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.min.css', array("storefront-style") );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles' );
```

и положите файл `bootstrap.min.css` в папку дочерней темы.

Comment: Положил стили в дочернюю тему, смотрю в браузер а там <link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" href=".../wp-content/themes/storefront/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.8.2" type="text/css" media="all"> Все стили и скрипты пути пишет в storefront

Comment: Вы точно скопировали код? stylesheet, а не template

Comment: Спасибо моя ошибка была.

Comment: Хороший совет. Отлично работает с каждым отдельным файлом из папки css, скопированной в дочернюю тему. Но там этих файлов ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО. Есть функция, которая сразу на всю папку перенаправит?

Comment: Такой функции нет. Но всю папку перенаправлять - плохое решение. Работайте только с теми файлами, что правите.